Using STM32 to have audio communication over bluetooth
I want to connect to a phone via Bluetooth using STM32 and transfer audio through a speaker and a microphone. What would be your recommendation for which controller to use and which codec to use?
I would be grateful if you could provide me with useful resources.

Which STM32 did you have in mind? are there STM32 with bluetooth hardware embedded? if not, you'd need a different microcontroller that has bluetooth. As soon as you do, you wouldn't use your STM32 anymore…
